# Explore the convergence of the integral $\int \:\frac{dx}{arccos\left(x\right)}$

Tags: integration

$$\int _0^1\frac{dx}{\arccos\left(x\right)}$$

Again, I want to open the question, because it is not enough to decide me :(

Comment: $\arccos(x)=t$, so...

Comment: Do you really have to find an anti-derivative? Because as far as I know there exists non in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Yes. Need to find him

Comment: Maple writes the answer in terms of $\displaystyle\int {\sin x \over x}\,dx$.

Comment: Please, help me :((((

Comment: According to WolframAlpha we have $\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\arccos(x)}=-\operatorname{Si}(\arccos(x))$ with $\operatorname{Si}(x)$ being the sine integral already given by Carl Heckman. So there seems to be no nice way to find the anti-derivative which leads to me asking my question again: do you really have to find the anti-derivative or do you just need some specific values?

Comment: If it helps, I changed the job

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: I changed the job

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arccosine is defined on $[-1,1]$, with range $[0,\pi]$, so we only have a problem at the upper bound. If we do the substitution
$$
t=\arccos x
$$
then we get
$$
x=\cos t
$$
and $dx=-\sin t\,dt$; thus the integral becomes
$$
\lim_{b\to1}\int_{0}^b\frac{1}{\arccos x}\,dx=
\lim_{b\to1}\int_{\pi/2}^{\arccos b}-\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt=
\lim_{c\to 0}\int_{c}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt
$$
Do you see any convergence problem?

If you don't want to perform the substitution, consider that
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\arccos x}{(1-x)^k}=
\lim_{x\to 1}-\frac{1}{k(1-x)^{k-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
is finite and nonzero for $k-1=-1/2$, that is, $k=1/2$. Thus
$$
\frac{1}{\arccos x}\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}
$$
and
$$
\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx
$$
obviously converges.

No “analytical” formula is available for the value of the integral, except expressing it as $\operatorname{Si}(\pi/2)$.

Comment: Oh my God, thank you very much, I didn't know what to do!